# Sentiment Analysis API for Multiple Dimensions i.e. Positivity, Emotionality etc

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have big chucks of text in English (avg length 800 words) which I would like to evaluate with a good and reliable sentiment analysis API.

Some threads seem to suggest APIs like [Alchemy](http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/sentiment/) but I would like an evaluation of the sentiment along **multiple dimensions** and not just a single score. Example of such dimensions could be Positivity and Emotionality etc.

Do you know any APIs that would provide such more elaborate results?

Comment: My suggestion, for better result, write it yourself.

Comment: While we don't have exactly what you have asked for, our SentiFindr API allows for sentiment tagging towards a particular entity. Plus you can optimize for precision or recall: https://www.mashape.com/dmitrykey/sentifindr

Answer (score 0):

The terms used in the natural language processing literature for positivity and emotionality are "valence" (or sometimes "polarity") and "arousal", respectively, so searching for APIs using those terms might be more useful to you. A quick search on those terms + sentiment + API revealed the following:

- http://talc2.loria.fr/empathic/ can give positivity (valence) as well as the specific type of emotion (e.g. "sadness" vs. "disgust")
- SentiStrength gives a positivity score as well as a negativity score. You can sum the scores to get positivity, or sum the absolute values of the score to get emotionality. For example a high-magnitude positivity score (+5) and a high-magnitude negativity score (-5) corresponds to high emotionality, but neutral positivity.
- Mashape's Repustate ( https://www.mashape.com/repustate/repustate-sentiment-and-text-analytics ) can give positivity towards different aspects of a service (e.g. pos/neg sentiment towards price, food, staff, location, atmosphere, events). Some of their other APIs on this list may also be of interest: http://blog.mashape.com/list-of-20-sentiment-analysis-apis/ . Apparently they used to have sentiment detection APIs specific to the dimensions of anger and excitement, but these seem to have been phased out.

Answer (score 0):

We recently [compared 15 Sentiment Analysis APIs](https://blog.inten.to/cloud-sentiment-analysis-vendor-overview-32d4bdaaf0c3). Here are some relevant points:

- sentiment score and positivity is essentially the same thing. Some APIs return the **sentiment score**, others - **sentiment polarity** labels (negative, positive etc) together with a **confidence** for each label. They could be mapped into each other (and we do that in our [uniform API](https://inten.to/api-platform/ai/text/sentiment)). The only difference is that the latter approach allows for expressing a **mixed** sentiment, while with the sentiment score it requires adding **sentiment agreement** (like [Meaning Cloud](https://www.meaningcloud.com/developer/sentiment-analysis) does).

  - **aspect-based sentiment** is when the subject can be evaluated along different dimensions or aspects. An example is a restaurant review, which may combine sentiment towards service, meals, and prices in one sentence. We have found aspect-based sentiment in [Aylien](https://aylien.com/text-api/), Meaning Cloud and [Repustate](https://www.repustate.com/text-analytics-api/), with different domain models available at each of the services.
  - **entity-based sentiment**. another way to get more details is to perform entity extraction and then to analyze sentiment towards each of the entities mentioned in the sentence. This is supported by [Google Cloud Natural Language](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/).
  - Additionally, Aylien and Meaning Cloud provide **sentiment subjectivity** score, measuring how subjective is the writer opinion.
  - Surprisingly, only Meaning Cloud provides explicit **irony detection**. It is not clear if it is used in other models implicitly.

Here's the picture:
[image: feature comparison for Sentiment Analysis APIs]

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this API: http://sentic.net/
They're doing sentiment analysis for a wide variety of different emotional dimensions at *concept level* and so much more...